# Delay for-loop each run

Tags: swift, for-loop, delay

I would like to run *hs.robber.step()* 6 times, every 2 seconds. With the code below it does wait 2 seconds and then it executes all 6 times at once.

Can you please find the error for me?

I used the code from here: [How to add a time delay in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189259/how-to-add-a-time-delay-in-swift)

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

func displayEscape() {
 for _ in 1...6 {

  let timeToDelay = Double(2)

  delay(timeToDelay) {
   self.hs.robber.step()
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why won't u use NSTimer?

Comment: What do you expect if you dispatch all closures with the same delay?

Comment: I am a beginner. I thought it would take 1, wait 2 seconds, execute step, take 2, wait 2 seconds.... etc.

Comment: If possible please give me an example with a NSTimer, I couldn't get it working. That's why I copied the code above in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dispatch_time() call creates a specific time in the future and not a relative change. Put its calculation within the loop like below.

```
func displayEscape() {
  let delay = Int64(2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
  for step in 1...6 {
    dispatch_after(
      dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64(step) * delay)),
      dispatch_get_main_queue(),
      { self.hs.robber.step() })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
Error:
binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Int64'

Comment: I did not get that error but have now cast step to an Int64. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the same delay for every iteration. You have to increment the delay every iteration to make it seem like you want (function every 2 seconds times 6). Something like:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

func displayEscape() {
    let timeToDelay: Double = 2
    var currentDelay: Double = 0
    for _ in 1...6 {
        currentDelay += timeToDelay
        delay(currentDelay) {
            self.hs.robber.step()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: somehow it didn't change anything :/

Comment: Simple check is if you replace self.s.robber.step() with print("Test"), you can see that it works. It must be something with your function then.